# Assembly: Echo paragraph symbol ¶ [Or any extended ASCII Character] called from character/string literal

Tags: assembly, character, echo, tasm

Using TASM and TLINK to Assemble:

**I'm able to show up** the *paragraph symbol* using `mov dl, 14h` or `mov dl, 20` 
Which are the dec and hex values to call for that symbol. 
Already an indication that it's already supported there...

However, echoes *called from literals* show up a *different character*, 
Using `mov dx, '¶'` this echoes this character `╢`, This surprised me 'cause those characters from dec 128 onwards can't be echoed using literal.

[image]

CODE:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.code
    mov ah, 02h

    mov dl, 20  ;Using ASCII number for paragraph symbol
    int 21h
    mov dx, '¶' ;Using A character literal
    int 21h

    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
end
```

How could I echo paragraph symbol ¶ called from character/string literal?

Comment: The console code page probably doesn't support it. I didn't immediately see the paragraph symbol on [asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Visual interpretation of characters depends on the used font. MS Windows uses OEM fonts for console applications. To find out which code corresponds with the desired glyph, open a console window (run CMD.EXE), select the code page, e.g.

```
C:>chcp 437
```

and try to enter decimal code of your character on numpad, holding Alt key pressed. On my WinXP computer it worked with Alt-0182, which is Unicode PILCROW SIGN 0x00B6=182. 
See also http://vitsoft.info/opta-biw.gif

Comment: I think does not have something to do with font, as I have mentioned, I can echo the `¶` symbol using dec 20(aslo 0182 as you have mentioned) which means it's there and the console support it but not with literals

Answer (score 0):

It is an encoding problem. You should take a look at your file with a hex editor to see how the `¶` character has been encoded by your text editor.

when looking at my encoding reference, the `¶` is at different places in the character table depending on the encoding:

- in the plain old CP437 (DOS Latin US): 0x14
- in CP850 (DOS Latin1 for Europe): 0xF4
- in CP1252 (Windows Latin1 = Window native encoding):  0xB6

Not surprisingly, the CP437 `╢` is 0xB6, so your file must be encoded in CP1252.

There is no problem to use character litterals in assembly, but the encoding used matters.